# Winforms DataGridView not updating after two quick clicks on checkbox

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I'm working on an application with a `DataGridView` bound to a list of entities. The last column is a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` that toggles between 0 and 1 to set the `Status` property of the entity. I handle the `CellContentClick` event of the `DataGridView`, and if the cell is a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`, I call `DataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewErrorContexts.CurrentCellChanged)`.

I'm also handling the `CellValueChanged` event, so that when the status changes, I can set the `CreatedDate` property to either `DateTime.Now` or an instance of `Nullable<DateTime>`, based on the value of the cell.

When clicking a checkbox like a normal person, everything works just fine, and as expected. The corresponding `DataGridViewCell` for `CreatedDate` updates instantly.

If I click the checkbox quickly twice in a row, however, the `CreatedDate` in the grid ends up displaying the appropriate value for the first of those two clicks. I'm not talking about double-click speed, either--it is at a much more moderate speed.

Now, the good thing is that the actual underlying data is being changed appropriately. So I know that the appropriate events are firing and that the handlers are being hit. But for whatever reason, the `DataGridView` is not getting the update. I've tried manually calling `Refresh()`, disabling the whole form after the click and reenabling it after the entity is saved (in this case, the second click still registered, because the time between disable and reenable ends up being quite short), and nothing works.

Ideas?

Comment: Not sure what is causing this, but does your binded entities implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and do you raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the entity setters? That is often the surest way that the `datagridview` will get the message that a value has changed.